# Can I import the process using session ID in my endpoints

Tags: php, processmaker

Is it possible to import the process using session ID in my endpoints(REST API)?

I need to import process using only username, password and session id not with the client id, client secret and access token.

Yes you are right. I can use the access tokens but in my endpoints I don't want use it. Because I have the no. of workspaces. So every time I can't create the client id and client secret for the every workspaces it's difficult.

**

My problem:
**

So I need to import process only using onlyusername, password and session id in my end points(REST API).

Support me to do this processmaker??

Comment: I doubt it. Most applications that implement access tokens do so because you should never be using client username/passwords directly to get access to an API. Why can't you use an access token?

Answer (score 0):

To use the rest api, you have to use the client id and client secret, as that is the oauth standard. Anyway you can login with a standard oauth protocol should be supported in ProcessMaker.

If you only want to use user/pass, I would suggest looking at the soap api. It is no longer actively supported, but a number of the inner working plugins and features utilize it so you should be good with that.

http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/ProcessMaker_WSDL_Web_Services